# mongodb error: { "$err" : "invalid operator: $geoWithin", "code" : 10068 }

Tags: mongodb, geojson

I am having this error when I try to query geometries using $geoWithin or $geoIntersects

```
error: { "$err" : "invalid operator: $geoWithin", "code" : 10068 }
```

I try to follow [this example](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/03/mongodb-geospatial-indexing-search-geojson-point-linestring-polygon/) with mongo v2.4.9 (on linux mint, I must say that I had trouble updating to v2.4.9, so I manually replaced the binaries in /usr/bin/ with the one from the [latest release](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads), I run mongod --upgrade afterwards)

---

Here is the code from the example:

```
s = db.shapes

s.insert( {_id: "P1", shape: {type: "Point", coordinates: [2,2] } } )
s.insert( {_id: "P2", shape: {type: "Point", coordinates: [3,6] } } )
s.insert( {_id: "Poly1", shape: {type: "Polygon", coordinates: [[ [3,1], [1,2], [5,6], [9,2], [4,3], [3,1] ]] } })
s.insert( {_id: "LS1", shape: {type: "LineString", coordinates: [ [5,2], [7,3], [7,5], [9,4] ] } } )

s.ensureIndex({shape: "2dsphere"})

BOX = {type: "Polygon", coordinates: [[ [0,0], [3,0], [3,3], [0,3], [0,0] ]] }

s.find( {shape: {$geoIntersects: {$geometry: BOX}}}, {_id:1})
```

then I have:

```
error: { "$err" : "invalid operator: $geoIntersects", "code" : 10068 }
```

or

```
s.find( { shape :  { $geoWithin : { $box : [ [ 0 , 0 ] ,  [ 100 , 100 ] ] } } } )
```

then I have:

```
error: { "$err" : "invalid operator: $geoWithin", "code" : 10068 }
```

---

This works fine on OS X with mongo 2.4.3

Comment: can you please show the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the version itself. Check Mongo is throwing a syntax error due to "$geoIntersects" doesn't exist, it was changed from $intersects to $geoIntersects so I would try to run the same code using:

```
s.find( {shape: {$intersects: {$geometry: BOX}}}, {_id:1})
```

If you have the old version it will work. $geoWithin has the same problem, it's not found by Mongo. Check your version with

```
version()
```

I'm sure it's an installation problem, I tried this code in a 2.4.7 and it works, it doesn't in an old version and I had to switch to $intersects

Comment: yes it was probably a version problem. I had the correct version of mongo running, but probably still a problem with the old database. I managed to delete my databases to reset everything, and now it works.

Comment: Did you try to run $intersects? Might be the database itself has inside the version which belongs to, I don't know this detail and it would nice to know.

Comment: I didn't try, and I can't try since I delete all the previous databases... But it was probably something like that.

Comment: It could have been great to know, I don't have a database migrated to test it. Good you fixed it